# Swift - read above cell value in tableview

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

Basically I am trying to get a value from a custom `table view cell`, as I have made 5 prototype cells - each with a different `tableViewCell class`. However, what I am trying to do is to read the data from the cell above. I have called my classes: `TableViewCell1, TableViewCell2` etc... So on the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I have the code like this:

```
if indexPath.row == 1 {
   let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("secondCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TierCell2      

   return cell2
}
```

This works, but I have also tried to do it like this, to be able to access the value above (with no luck) - which only results in an optional value error.

```
let cell1:TableViewCell1 = TableViewCell1()
cell2.PriceText.text = cell1.PriceText.text
```

Any ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Comment: More information might help as we what you are trying to achieve. As the tableViewCells are dequed for the cells that are currently being displayed, what you need to do is get the information you are looking for from the data source.... But if you provide more info what you are trying to achieve maybe things might be clearer....

Comment: @Azzaknight Basically I am trying to display a price tier view, showing the users set price tier for a specific service. I want to display the value from an array of dictionaries, and then show it in a tableview. That's not a problem - however; to ensure that a value isn't displayed twice - or don't have any spaces in the tableView, I need to check if the value is shown in the cell above. Much like:

if allTiers[0][2] != nil && cellAbove.PriceText.text != allTiers[0][2] {
cell2.PriceText.text = allTiers[0][2]
}

Comment: Then my next question - why the 5 separate custom table cells? Why not one custom cell with the 5 labels to display the tiered data ?

Comment: @Azzaknight to be honest, I don't know. I just thought it would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you then try creating one custom table view cell with the 5 price tier labels that you want to display. Then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath you just deque a cell as the custom class and fill in all the tier information that you already have in your dictionary and return that cell.

Comment: I have done that now. However, I need to sort my dictionary by key (descending order), as I have a dictionary of [Int:Int], and then display it in the tableView with the data. How exactly would I do this?

Comment: My next question - why is your data structure a dictionary? What is the data that you are storing in the dictionary?